# Passing data between a ViewController and a Sprite Kit class

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, boolean

I want to use a `BOOL` property, that is declared in my `GameScene.h` which is a subclass of a SKScene, in my `ViewController.m` file.  I tried using this in the `ViewController.m` but it doesn't work:

`#import "GameScene.h";`

The BOOL is declared in `GameScene.h`as:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL gameover;`

And when I want to use that BOOL property in `ViewController.m` I don't know how to access to the `GameScene.h` file.

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more code?

Comment: Store your variable by using NSUserDefaults or a Singleton. Google "Passing data between scenes" for more info.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not needed in this scenario, since scene is an object in the view controllers view, however,  more code is needed to correctly answer this, because it sounds like you are not accessing your scene correctly.  You may want to do something like ((self.view as SKView).scene as GameScene).gameover